# Why is WLST not recognizing the user/password in the key and config file in connect() call?

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I'm trying to connect to an admin server in WLST using config and key files. There are no error messages but I am prompted for a username and password. These files were created (by another developer who is long gone[1]) with the `storeUserConfig()` command. My call to connect looks something like this: `connect(userConfigFile=configFile, userKeyFile=keyFile, url='t3://somehost:7031')`).

Is there some restriction in using these files, such as it can only be used on the host where created, or it needs access to the domain's `boot.properties` file?

Note: I'm trying to connect to an admin server on a different host and non-standard port (e.g. not 7001). The server I am running WLST on and the remote host are the same version of Weblogic.

Some of the things I have tried:

- verified that these files appear correct, the key file being binary data and the config file having a line for "weblogic.management.username={AES}..." and "weblogic.management.password={AES}...".
- verified that there is a server on the specified port by entering a known login and password that is successful
- specified the admin server in the connect parameter
- turn on `debug(true)`; the only output is `<wlst-debug> connect : Will check if userConfig and userKeyFile should be used to connect to the server` and another line giving the path to the userConfig file
- turn on Python logging in jython with -Dpython.verbose=debug; nothing relevant to decryption operation
- Munging the key or the config files generates no error messages and behaviour as above

[1]: These files are still used today by other existing WLST scripts. However, these scripts are so convoluted and deliberately obfuscated that they are very difficult to reverse-engineer how `connect()` is being called.

Comment: Have you tried connecting without the config files to see if that works or you get a new error? `connect('user', 'pass', 't3://somehost:7031' )` Like COLINHY mentioned, it should not matter that it's on a different host.

Comment: @casting That works without the files. I also can connect when I enter the username and password at the prompts.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to access to the domain's `boot.properties` file. You just need to make sure the `configFile`  and  `keyFile` pointing to the right files. FYI, here is one of the commands we are using:`connect(userConfigFile='./user.secure',userKeyFile='./key.secure',url='t3://somehost:7001')`

Comment: It works for me too with a local installation of Weblogic at localhost:7001 with the call as you illustrated, but using this same connect call to an AdminServer on a different host and non-standard port is not working (added this detail to the question too).

Comment: Definitely it is not because of port or remote host of AdminServer. Actually I does not use the default port and always connect to the AdminServer remotely.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info that remote host doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the network connectity that might be having a firewall in between that troubling you, check the traceroute from the script machine to the Remote machine. Recently I have faced simalar issue. once the routing table updated with allow the WL admin server port everything got set.

Hope this could helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @pavan-wla, but I know that there isn't a problem with connectivity because I get a prompt for a user/password, and when I enter valid values my WLST script executes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. In a script, I exported the Linux variables userConfigFile and userKeyFile. Then I connected by running:

```
  url='t3://localhost:7002'
  userConfigFile='$userConfigFile'
  userKeyFile='$userKeyFile'
  connect(userConfigFile=$userConfigFile, userKeyFile=#userKeyFile, url=url)
```

That all worked in a script, but would not work interactively. I changed to doing the following:

```
  url='t3://localhost:7002'
  userConfigFile='/users/me/weblogic-2014/weblogic-admin-WebLogicConfig.properties'
  userKeyFile='/users/me/weblogic-2014/weblogic-admin-WebLogicKey.properties'
  connect(userConfigFile=userConfigFile, userKeyFile=userKeyFile, url=url)
```

And that worked interactively.